# How To Get an LLVM IR or Object Code From a Source Code Inside a Tool (Inside C++ Code)

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, clang, llvm

I am trying to write a tool which will get target triple as a command option and a C or C++ code, will get and change LLVM IR code inside (maybe adding a pass or meaningless operation for now), will get and change object code from changed LLVM IR, and lastly will give output as an executable file.
Example tool in summary as I thought:

Usage (I can add some command line options later):
`mytool --triple riscv32 example.c`

Sequence of this complete tool:

```
Run Tool --> Get Target Triple --> Get LLVM IR code from source code --> Change LLVM IR code --> Get Object Code from llvm ir code --> Change Object Code --> Give Executable File Output
```

For this, firstly I thought implement this part of code to get file and target triple:

```
#include "llvm/Support/CommandLine.h"

static cl::list<std::string>
InputFilenames(cl::Positional, cl::desc("<input files>"),cl::ZeroOrMore);

extern cl::opt<std::string> TripleName;

cl::opt<std::string>
llvm::TripleName("triple", cl::desc("<target triple>"));
```

Suppose that I did more coding and get source code file in main function, after that how can I get LLVM IR or object code inside my tool(my c++ tool written using llvm c++ api) and apply on some operations?

I am asking this because for example we can use a pass in command line as:

`opt -load libMyPass.so -mypass example.ll -o output.ll`
or in clang with `-Xclang -load -Xclang` option.

or this is more proper example:
`clang -mem2reg example.ll -o output.ll`

And we can also use these passes in our codes (in other passes or tools):

```
static std::unique_ptr<legacy::FunctionPassManager> TheFPM;  
TheFPM->add(createPromoteMemoryToRegisterPass());
TheFPM->run(*TheFunction);
```

(TheFunction should be declared before.)

or maybe with addPass function (I am not sure.)
https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1PassManager.html#a314ff184ce4ace8801e1158ef909e22e

or like using an analysis pass inside another different pass:

```
void LegacyAnotherPass::getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &Info) const {
  Info.addRequired<LegacyMyAnalysisPass>();
}
```

As we can pass our passes to command line and do nearly same thing in c++ api I thought that we can also do other command line operations inside our code. I am trying to find a function or a piece of code which should be a code equivalent for other compilation commands. For example:

For getting llvm ir code from source code we can use this command:

`clang -S -emit-llvm example.c -o example.ll`

That I thought as code equivalent symbolically (maybe we can save code to a string  after getting):

`llvmir = file.getLLVMIRCode("target triple", "other options");`

For getting object code from llvm ir code we can use this command:

`clang -c example.ll -o example.o`

That I thought as code equivalent:

`objcode = llvmir.getObjectCode("target triple", "other options");`

Is there a way like this in simply and how I can?

Maybe you can say "write a bash script and do operations step by step" or "use c++ system(); function to do command line operation" but I want to write this complete tool using llvm and its functions inside.

There is a tutorial for Kaleidoscope language for emitting object code from generated llvm ir code with llvm c++ api here:
https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/LangImpl08.html

this simply shows what I think like but this comes from after lexing, parsing and llvm ir generating sequence and applying on themodule variable declared before however I don't want my c or c++ code to lex parse again already clang can do this :) So I couldn't integrate this thing but as you can see similar jobs.

Also I asked this question on llvm-dev mailing list but I couldn't get a proper answer probably I was misunderstood:

https://groups.google.com/g/llvm-dev/c/-FZzADPRNKY

IN SUMMARY:

I want to compile any step of code sequence (like llvm ir code, object code, assembly code) and save them to strings with LLVM C++ API but I couldn't find any proper function for that. If there is no simple way, do I really need deep into llvm or clang source libraries and where should I start to look?

Comment: What you want is entirely possible. Maybe 500 lines of C++ in all, using several dozen LLVM classes. Noone's likely to give you a step-by-step description of how to do it, though. If you run into problems along the way, feel free to ask, but until then I'll vote to close this as lacking in focus.

Comment: @arnt Yes, you are right but actually I don't want a step by step description. I know I can do this with dozens lines of code but probably for this I should be a master on almost entire library and I am not sure where to start and also whether worth it. I am  just trying to find a way to get rid of dozens lines of code because -I am mistaken or not- there should be a simple way to do this that someone knows. Like this as I mentioned: https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/LangImpl08.html

Comment: You won't need even nearly the entire library. Very far from it. What you want is called writing a compiler driver, I've done it (different in all the details, of course) and it took a week. Just start on it. Find some code on github that uses the pass manager, sets up a target machine, etc., spend a day getting familiar with the classes and start writing the code. It's not worse than most other tasks you could do in a week.

Comment: @arnt Thanks for encouragement! We wrote a prototype tool that does encryption in compiler level and published as a paper in 52nd IEEE/IFIP DSN Conference. Check out our paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9833625 and github: https://github.com/kasirgalabs/ERIC

Comment: Also, who anyone looking for an answer to this question, can check our github to get the logic, although details are different.